# Should i validate if related entity exists before insert?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

```
class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Sale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}

class SaleService
{

    public void NewSale(Sale sale)
    {
        //Should i validate if Customer exists by sale.CustomerId before call save?

        saleRepository.InsertOrUpdate(sale);
    }
}
```

I'm using Domain Driven Design and Entity Framework.
Should i validate if Customer exists by sale.CustomerId before call save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually don't do that. Normally, these information comes from the client which **was loaded** before (it existed). However, there are cases that the `CustomerId` is missing at the time you update your db.

- Due to concurrency when many users access the system at the same time. But this case should be solved **selectively** using optimistic concurrency control (version). We usually don't try to handle concurrency in all the cases as it's almost impossible to do so and doing that also has side effects like performance issues, complexity,... We focus only on some critical code in the system that would cause problems if there is a concurrency issue.
- A client tries to hack the system by sending an inappropriate `CustomerId`. But this is another issue that should be checked based on authorization or something like that.

In most of the cases, I think a foreign key constraint in db is enough.

Comment: What about distributed systems?

Comment: @plalx: what do you mean distributed systems: distributed databases, or distributed application servers? In case of distributed application servers, there should not be any difference because the request from every server should not be different from db server point of view

Comment: Imagine that a User is making a sale and selected customer.
Another user deleted the customer selected by the first user.
When the first user tries to save, a foreign key error is generated.

Thinking about it, to minimize the cases, I thought I would add a "deleted" column instead of deleting records. This would be an appropriate practice?

A side effect is that I would have to create filtered indexes to unique columns.

Comment: @KhanhTO I meant both, distributed databases and application servers. In that case you can't really rely on foreign keys to enforce such policies.

Comment: @Vinicius Gonçalves: that's the case of concurrency control. If you don't delete the record, just mark it as "deleted" then I'm not sure if there is any way to make foreign key work in this case. Using a normal check by loading the row into your application server does not work either because another user may still able to delete the row when it's loaded on the application server. In this case, you may need to load the row `with lock` to ensure no one else gets access to that row.

Comment: @plalx: I'm not sure if that's true